BigQuery Connectors Pivot Table Data Missing when Website Refreshed
[Error] 1We connect data with BQ to google sheets for analysis purposes. However, since yesterday when we refresh the gsheet link, the data connector works as expected, but pivot table created from the Connected Sheet throws an error. It used to work perfectly.
Tried creating a new pivot extract from another projects and queries but the data is shown at first but disappears as the sheet loads even the preview is stable. I get Error Loading data... error as in the image when the page is refreshed. Checked permissions for BQ and nothing wrong.

I'm currently encountering the same issue. Submitted bug reports to Google. It's happening with a couple of different files for our company.
One workaround that's worked temporarily is to make a copy of the file (and do no more BigQuery refreshes). That's at least allowed some users to temporarily access the data who were just getting the blank PivotTable, but it's not a real solution.
